# How to kill the longest running instance of a process

Tags: powershell

Let me preface this by saying yesterday was the first time I saw Powershell.

I'm trying to create a script that will kill the process "pptview" based on how long its been running. Specifically, I can have several instances of pptview  running at the same time but I only want to kill the one that has been running the longest.

So far I have created a script that searches if duplicate instances of  the process exist. If it doesn't find any it goes to sleep for 60 seconds then checks again.

I'm using taskkill to kill the process via the PID - which works well.

The bit I'm stuck on is how to determine which is the longest running instance and how to get the PID so I can feed it back to taskkill.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Perfectly fine answer, post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You does not have to use `taskkill` to kill process. You can use `Stop-Process` PowerShell cmdlet instead. To find the longest running process, you can sort processes by `StartTime` and select the first:

```powershell
Get-Process pptview|
Sort-Object StartTime|
Select-Object -First 1|
Stop-Process
```

But something says me, that you want to stop all but the youngest one:

```powershell
Get-Process pptview|
Sort-Object StartTime -Descending|
Select-Object -Skip 1|
Stop-Process
```

Comment: Thanks. You did in 4 lines what took me 30 and the difference is yours works. Thanks again!!!